# "Axle cap": what is it called and how to remove it?

Tags: repair, tools, hand-tools

I've put together a wagon for a child, but I've messed up something. Now I need to remove a plastic cap that has metal bits inside and that goes over the end of the wheel axle. A spare part of this cap looks like this:
[image]
[image]

> What is this part called and what tool can I use to remove it? As I have a spare part, I don't mind destroying the original cap during removal but if there is a way to remove it without destroying it, I'm interested in knowing as well.

p.s.

I include as well this pic to show where the cap goes in the wagon:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just pressure fit onto the axle. Take a pair of pliers or vise grips and get good grip on the nut, gently pull and twist at the same time, back and forth back and forth.

It may take some time to get it off.

Comment: They are generally not reusable.

Comment: They are referred to as axle PAL nuts or axle caps. They are sized based on the axle diameter. Replacements are available in the hardware section of most home improvement centers.

Answer (score 6):

I assembled toys, displays, and bicycles for a major retailer for 7 years.  I despise removing those caps in a recessed hole like the center of a plastic wheel.  You can snap the plastic cover off, then use vice grips, pliers, a screw driver, or wire cutters to twist, bend, pry, or cut the metal part to remove it.  They're almost always destroyed during removal so expect to use that spare to replace it.

Comment: And, in fact, removal is much easier if one goes in with the single-use mentality that "I'm going to replace that part anyway, so the sooner I cut it or it breaks the sooner I'll have it removed."